# fetching taxonomy tree from database from query

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-database

I add a vocablary named "product sub categories" and I want to fetch the whole tree structure from datebase through query? Can anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the Drupal API taxonomy_get_tree function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/7), you only need the vocabulary id.

```
$taxonomyTree = taxonomy_get_tree($vid);
```

If you are using Drupal 7, you can use [taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load/7) to get the vocabulary object by its name.

```
$vocabularyObject = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load("product sub categories");
```

Comment: `$vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load("product sub categories");
$terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vocabulary);` ,here "product sub categories" is my vocabulary, I want to print the whole tree but didnt get any result from this

Comment: Try with taxonomy_get_tree($vocabulary->vid); Also you can debug your variables to check correct results.

Comment: Thanku so much @mario :)